# Is there a way to default clion working directory as project directory?

Tags: cmake, ide, clion

As a student I create many (small) projects and I sometimes forget to do this.
As a result, I spend sometimes expensive time debugging the program until I understand to cold truth.
In short, is there a way to default CLion working directory as project directory?
I don't mean using a template or any of the solutions I still need to remember an extra step.

Tried a template with

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Tried a macro in "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "CMake":
`-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}`.

Tried finding the default template for new project, with no success.

Comment: working directory of _what_ process? And to clarify, you want to make that working directory be same path as the project directory?

Comment: @starball On the Run Config [link](https://prnt.sc/kl_xs5jZUny7)